# How to avoid default project creation in IWizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vsix, visual-studio-extensions

**The requirement:**

User has to create project at a specified path (say under the C:\MyProject\XYZTest).If not (say user gave C:\MyProject\DummyFolder) then the application should terminate without creating any project.

Observe the below code

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
        {
            try
            {
                string l_basepath = string.Empty;
                var ProjectProperties = project.ProjectItems;
                var SolnPath = ProjectProperties.Item(1).FileNames[1];

                if (SolnPath.IndexOf("XYZTest") > 0)
                {
                       //set the project path
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select valid project location");
                    Application.Exit();

                }
}
```

The code is performing a check that if the project  location path contains "XYZLocation" string, then only the user can go ahead and create the project else the application should exit.

This works but the point is that, after exiting also it creates the default project. Because we have implemented it in the  "ProjectFinishedGenerating" method of IWizard.

So, inorder to avoid this situation , I think that we need to do it in the **"RunStarted"** method of IWizard. But there I am unable to get the

```
var ProjectProperties = project.ProjectItems;
 var SolnPath = ProjectProperties.Item(1).FileNames[1];
```

The question is

```
a) Is my idea and approach is correct (to do in the RunStarted method)?
b)If so, how can I do it?
c)If not, what is the way to achieve so?
```

Means, if the application exist, there shoould not be any project generated at any location  specified by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I have is *Application.Exit();*.
This solution is not valid, because it kill the whole visual studio.